# Acer Aspire One D270 netbook as a main coding machine for Java, PHP and C++

Tags: php, c++, xampp

Can I use Acer Aspire One D270 net-book for programming
It has got a dual core processor, Atom  N2600 and 2 GBs of RAM.
As it was launched recently I searched many forums but no one answered my question.
I will also be running XAMPP as a part-time development server.
I would use Netbeans 7.0.1 ,Notepad++ and Dev C++ on Windows 7 Ultimate for C++, C ,PHP and Java Development. I would also use Vim and Emacs on Ubuntu. I am thinking that there wont be any latency in compiling and the build process.
My main query is that if I can use this net-book with a 24 inch monitor and external mouse and keyboard as my main coding machine with.
I chose this machine over other because it is relatively cheap and reasonable.
I am a class 8 student and I like to code.
As i am always on move because I have to go to many tutions and get very less time for coding I want to buy a portable computer

Comment: Probably better suited for superuser

Comment: Should be fine... Recalls coding on a 386dx...

Comment: Depends what you want to do. But as you don't seem to do scientific computing or any other extremely labour intensive stuff, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be ok, you will get portability and with than monitor also nice working station.
I was doing my java projects on an old asus F5N laptop with 2GB of ram and it worked great.

One thing is that I would not use dev-c++, rather install latest code blocks and mingw.

Answer (score 1):

Atom N2600 should be be enough for C++/PHP java is requires more resources especially if you are going to use eclipse (CPU is not a problem you need a lot of RAM for java 4 GB or more)
I was developing on Win x86 machine with 3 GB or RAM its ok for a wile.

Comment: Thank Sir.This means that on this setup I would be able to code C++ and PHP efficiently. Thanks for so fast reply